# How can I use StopWatch with TimeSpan and two checkBoxes to decide if the timer will count up or down?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want that if the checkBox checkBoxCountDown is checked then the timer will count down if the timer is already working running then start counting down from the point it was. And if the checkbox is checked before starting the timer before clicking the start button and the time is 00:00:00:000 don't count down. But if the time is for example 01:00:00:000 or for example 00:00:00:011 then clicking on start will count down and it should stop when getting to 00:00:00:000

Same idea with checkBoxCountUp.

The idea is to make that the checkboxes will decide if to count up or down but I'm not sure how to do it with the stopwatch.

StopWatch can count only up?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace StopwatchTimer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static readonly Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        private long diff = 0, previousTicks = 0, ticksDisplayed = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            richTextBox1.TabStop = false;
            richTextBox1.ReadOnly = true;
            richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
            richTextBox1.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            richTextBox1.Enter += RichTextBox1_Enter; ;

            UpdateTime();
        }

        private void RichTextBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnStart.Focus();
        }

        private void UpdateTime()
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = GetTimeString(watch.Elapsed);
        }

        private string GetTimeString(TimeSpan elapsed)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            //calculate difference in ticks
            diff = elapsed.Ticks - previousTicks;

            if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
            { //counting up
                ticksDisplayed += diff;
            }
            else
            { //counting down
                ticksDisplayed -= diff;
            }

            if (ticksDisplayed < 0)
            {
                ticksDisplayed = 0;
            }

            //Make ticksDisplayed to regular time to display in richtextbox
            TimeSpan ctimeSpan = new TimeSpan(ticksDisplayed);

            result = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:000}",
                ctimeSpan.Hours,
                ctimeSpan.Minutes,
                ctimeSpan.Seconds,
                ctimeSpan.Milliseconds);

            previousTicks = elapsed.Ticks;

            return result;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnStart.Text == "START")
            {
                diff = 0;
                previousTicks = 0;
                ticksDisplayed = 0;

                watch.Reset();
                watch.Start();
                UpdateTime();
                btnStart.Text = "STOP";
                timer1.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                watch.Stop();
                btnStart.Text = "START";
                btnPause.Text = "PAUSE";
                timer1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            diff = 0;
            previousTicks = 0;
            ticksDisplayed = 0;

            watch.Reset();
            watch.Start();
            UpdateTime();
        }

        private void trackBarHours_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void trackBarMinutes_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void trackBarSeconds_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnStart.Text == "STOP")
            {
                if (btnPause.Text == "PAUSE")
                {
                    btnPause.Text = "CONTINUE";
                    watch.Stop();
                    timer1.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    btnPause.Text = "PAUSE";
                    watch.Start();
                    timer1.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateTime();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, why have 2 checkboxes for count up and count down?  One checkbox is enough - when it's checked, count up, when it's unchecked, count down.
Or use radio buttons, so when you check one, the other is automatically unchecked.

A Stopwatch will only count up.  If you want to count down, you set it running and then subtract its time from your initial duration.
So if you want it to count down from 5 minutes, set it running and when you display the time, subtract its time from 5 minutes to get how much time is remaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use `radiobuttons` but it is your choice. In order to do what you want you need to calculate the time(ticks) difference between two successive `UpdateTime()` calls and *add* or *subtract* that from the time displayed. You also need to keep track of the time displayed so you can update it every time the timer ticks.

Code:

```
//I am counting everything in Stopwatch ticks
private long diff = 0, previousTicks = 0, ticksDisplayed = 0;

private string GetTimeString( TimeSpan elapsed ) {
    string result = string.Empty;

    //calculate difference in ticks
    diff = elapsed.Ticks - previousTicks;

    //You can use checkBoxCountUp or checkBoxCountDown instead
    if( radioButton1.Checked == false && radioButton2.Checked == false ) {
        //do nothing
    }
    else if( radioButton1.Checked == true ) { //counting up
        ticksDisplayed += diff;
    }
    else { //counting down
        ticksDisplayed -= diff;
    }

    if( ticksDisplayed < 0) {
        ticksDisplayed = 0;
    }

    //Make ticksDisplayed to regular time to display in richtextbox
    TimeSpan ctimeSpan = new TimeSpan( ticksDisplayed );

    result = string.Format( "{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:000}",
        ctimeSpan.Hours,
        ctimeSpan.Minutes,
        ctimeSpan.Seconds,
        ctimeSpan.Milliseconds );

    previousTicks = elapsed.Ticks;

    return result;
}
```

Also **don't forget** to set `diff, previousTicks, ticksDisplayed` to *zero* every time you reset the `Stopwatch`!

**EDIT**

Code with trackbars:

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll( object sender, EventArgs e ) { //hour
    //get ticksDisplayed as TimeSpan
    TimeSpan ctimeSpan = new TimeSpan( ticksDisplayed );
    //change only the hour
    TimeSpan htimeSpan = new TimeSpan( ctimeSpan.Days, trackBar1.Value, ctimeSpan.Minutes,
                                       ctimeSpan.Seconds, ctimeSpan.Milliseconds );

    //set it to ticksDisplayed and update.
    ticksDisplayed = htimeSpan.Ticks;


    UpdateTime();
}

private void trackBar2_Scroll( object sender, EventArgs e ) { //min
    TimeSpan ctimeSpan = new TimeSpan( ticksDisplayed );
    TimeSpan mtimeSpan = new TimeSpan( ctimeSpan.Days, ctimeSpan.Hours, trackBar2.Value,
                                       ctimeSpan.Seconds, ctimeSpan.Milliseconds );

    ticksDisplayed = mtimeSpan.Ticks;


    UpdateTime();
}

private void trackBar3_Scroll( object sender, EventArgs e ) { //sec
    TimeSpan ctimeSpan = new TimeSpan( ticksDisplayed );
    TimeSpan stimeSpan = new TimeSpan( ctimeSpan.Days, ctimeSpan.Hours, ctimeSpan.Minutes,
                                       trackBar3.Value, ctimeSpan.Milliseconds );

    ticksDisplayed = stimeSpan.Ticks;


    UpdateTime();
}
```

Now when ever you reset the `Stopwatch` you need to set time like this:

```
watch.Reset();
TimeSpan ctimeSpan = new TimeSpan( 0, trackBar1.Value, trackBar2.Value, trackBar3.Value, 0 );
diff = 0;
previousTicks = 0;
ticksDisplayed = ctimeSpan.Ticks;
```

Comment: Working great. I have another sub question. I added now 3 trackBars to the designer and added to the code each trackBar scroll event. I want to do that inside each trackBar scroll event when changing the trackBar value it will change the value of time in the richTextBox either when the stopwatch is already running or before starting it. The idea i to use 3 trackBars one for hours one for minutes one for seconds to set the timer time either in real time or before starting it. How can I do it ? Updated my question the code with the scroll events.